# Showing a calculated value in the geometry nodes modifier stack

Tags: geometry-nodes

I would like to **show a calculated value in the geometry nodes modifier stack**.

**Example:**

A user inputs a value then geometry nodes does some calculations then shows the calculated value in the geometry nodes modifier stack.  I tried sending it to the output group but it doesn't show.

I was thinking of maybe using something like **#input_value + #given_value (like using a #frame driver)** but **not sure how to get this to show in the geometry nodes modifier stack or access the calculated node value to output**.

**The red arrow is where I would like the calculated value to show up.**

Example setup:
[image: img1]

Comment: you cannot show the calculated value in the output. You can enter a variable in the output attribute and use this variable e.g. in the shader tree

Comment: This field is there to let you give a name to the attribute, not seeing its values. I think you want to use the spreadsheet editor rather

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK unfortunately this is not possible right now. You cannot show values in the modifier stack right now. You can only put a name/variable there and use this e.g. in the shaders tab.

If you wanna see values you can use the spreadsheet/viewer node.